# solr - searching part of words

Tags: solr

My field is defined as

```
<field name="PackageName" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

*text_en is defined as in the original schema.xml that comes with solr

Now, my field has the following vaues

- "one"
- "one1"

searching for "one" returns only the field "one".
What causes it? how can I change it?

Comment: whats the defination for field type text_en ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the words from an alphanumeric indexed term, you may want to check for the [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory).
WordDelimiterFilterFactory allows splitOnNumerics which would allow `One1` to be divided into `One` and `1` tokens and hence matching the Searched term `One`.
You can always `preserveOriginal` to match One1 as well.

Comment: Thanks. But as I understand WordDelimiterFilterFactory  will be a breaker. What if sometimes I have sku in the field (such as IT8U-ERET-X8XI and I want a search of X8XI to return the document)

Comment: What if I have a word like onetwo one searching for "one" returns only one search. I would like to return both one and onetwo.